# ruby 2.5 on ubuntu:latest error assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.5

I support Rails 4.2.5 application on Ruby 2.5. Packages and rails are ok, but when I run `rake assets:precompile` I have error.

```
eric>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/subscriber.rb:80:in `join'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/subscriber.rb:80:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:19:in `initialize'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/subscriber.rb:33:in `new'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/subscriber.rb:33:in `attach_to'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:75:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:138:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/wealthoz/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don't deploy intro docker containers on ruby 2.5 image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on production environment, try `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should stick with Ruby 2.3, you could experience many runtime errors with 2.5 (like this one you reported)

Comment: Thank you, Can the problem be due to the fact that I use Node.js to compile assets.

Comment: Definitely not, it's a Ruby runtime error related to ActiveSupport. Is this the full trace of the error (did you use `--trace` when you ran `rake assets:precompile`)?